# NBA round robin probability

Tags: probability

Let’s say there is a team who you expect to win 75% of its games in a given 82-game  NBA regular season (and the probability of winning each game = 75%). What is the probability that the team will never lose consecutive games at any point during the 82-game season.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a Markov chain with $3$ states, then find the $82$-th power of the transition matrix. Here is the transition matrix:
$$
P = \begin{pmatrix}
\frac 34 & \frac 14 & 0 \\
\frac 34 & 0 & \frac 14 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Your answer would be
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
P^{82}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
According to Wolfram Alpha, $1.29\%$ would be an estimate of the answer.

Comment: Hello there! What are the 3 states? Win, Loss, and? What do the 0s represent? Many thanks!

Comment: The states are: no loss since the last win, 1 loss since the last win, and 2 consecutive losses have occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Each loss is followed by a win.  Except for the last game.  Let's put a nominal win in Game 83.
If the team loses 41 games, they are followed by 41 wins, leaving just one win left over to put among the 41 LossWin pairs.  There are 42 places to put the extra win.
If the team loses 40 games, followed by 40 wins, with three games left over.  That is 40+3=43 places, and insert the three other games, which can be done in ${43}\choose{3}$ ways.