# Markov Chain Clarification

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I was looking at this question: [NBA round robin probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/440251/nba-round-robin-probability). I don't have enough reputation to add a follow up, so I am forced to make a new question. What is the purpose of the right-most matrix, $\begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 1 \\ 0
\end{pmatrix}$, in the most up-voted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you post-multiply a matrix with the vector,

$$M\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},$$you are summing up the first two columns of the matrix.

We are only interested in either $0$ loss and $1$ loss since last win. Hence we only add those columns.